# What constitutes a valid type in lean?

Tags: proof, theorem-proving, lean

I've done the first 3 chapters of the [lean tutorial](https://leanprover.github.io/tutorial/), and I've already [done a few proofs in propositional logic](https://github.com/picrin/lean).

Now I'm trying to go back a bit and [ask myself dumb questions](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/ask-yourself-dumb-questions-%E2%80%93-and-answer-them/.).

My understanding is that:

1. Terms can **have** types: `constant A : Type`. `A` is a term, `Type` is the type of `A`.
2. Terms can **become** types: `constant a : A`.
3. The type of a term **can depend** on the type of another term: `constant B : A -> Type`, which is sugar for `constant B' : Π (a : A), Type`

But this understanding is clearly wrong, for this code doesn't typecheck:

```
constant A : Type

constant a : A

constant B : A -> Type

constant B' : Π (a : A), Type

constant C : Π (b : B), Type

constant C' : Π (B : A), (Π (b : B), Type)

constant C'' : B -> Type
```

All lines beginning `constant C`, that is line 9, 11 and 13 throw an error `error: type expected at B`

Why? I suspect that not **all** terms can become types. I suspect that **terms whose types depend on other types can't become types**. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First type error

The problem with the first type error in

```
constant C : Π (b : B), Type
```

is that you cannot say `b : B`, because `B` is a *function* (without definition) of type `A -> Type`, i.e. `B` is a *value*, not a type.
It doesn't make sense to make a claim like `b : 1` or `b : "xyz"` or `b : (λ a : A, Type)`.

E.g. the following would work, since `B a : Type`:

```
constant C : Π (b : B a), Type
```

#### Second type error

The second type error in

```
constant C' : Π (B : A), (Π (b : B), Type)
```

stems from the fact that it is not known that `B` is a type, all we know about `B` is that it is some value (inhabitant) of type `A`. To be able to use `B` that way, you'll need something like this:

```
constant C' : Π (B : Type), (Π (b : B), Type)
```

i.e. we explicitly say `B` is a type.

#### Third type error

```
constant C'' : B -> Type
```

The reason this fails to typecheck is the same as in the first case. `B` is a function value, while we need a type here -- this is why `constant B : A -> Type` works.

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helps to clarify my understanding.

In particular, I am convinced that B is a function, for both these lines typecheck:

`check (B : (Π (a : A), Type))` and

`check ((λ (a : A), A) : (Π (a : A), Type))`.

I'm convinced `B` has **the same type** as `(λ (a : A), A)`, and therefore I'm convinced that B is a function.

This is very interesting, and I didn't realise that.

Comment: **(1)** Yes, but I believe you meant `Type` instead of `Prop` (or you'll need to change the definitions of `A` and `B`) **(2)** `constant` is a way to *postulate* some things without giving them a real *definition*. `constant` should be used with care because it can introduce inconsistencies into your development -- you wouldn't want to accidentally introduce something equivalent to `constant f : false` (or `axiom f : false`).

Comment: Let us revisit the first type error. `B` is a value (of type `A -> Type`), but not a type. However, `A` is both a value **and** a type. To see that it is a value, notice that `constant A : Type`. To see that it is a type, notice `constant a : A`. I see that values, which are functions cannot **become** types. Will all other values (i.e. values which are **not** functions) be eligible to become types? Taking a purely syntactic approach, why wouldn't `b : (λ a : A, Type)` make sense? (I realise that semantically it's pure nonsense).

Comment: (1) Thanks, I changed `Prop` to `Type` in my comment.

Comment: (2) Thanks, I understand that. Before I learned about `sorry`, I would use my own thing, which allowed me to temporarily prove any proposition `axiom always : Π (p : Prop), p`. Obviously I would comment it out after finishing my proof:

https://github.com/picrin/lean/blob/master/deMorgan.lean#L11

Comment: Syntactically, `(λ a : A, Type)` is not a type because it starts with `λ` (or `fun`).

Comment: I see. So the conclusion is that every term **can become** a type, unless it's type is a function.

Comment: Sorry, that's perhaps too far-fetched. A *conservative* conclusion, would be that terms, which are functions **can't become** types. My previous conclusion is a bit more adventurous (but perhaps also true).

Comment: Everything that does not live in `Type` is not a type. Off the top of my head: the already mentioned functions (`λ` / `fun`), data constructors (`zero`, `succ`, etc.), type constructors (`list`, `vector`).

Comment: When in doubt, you can use `check (<something> : Type)` to make sure you understand the nature of `<something>`.